# Creating Array out of comma seperated list in React JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, use-state

I have an input for users to come and paste one id or multiple with each seperated by a comma then run a function on the individual Id's.

```
<Input type={'text'} placeholder="Id(s) (seperated by comma if more than 1)" value={ids} onChange={(event) => setIds(event.target.value)} />
```

Then I have the React useState constants for using the individial ids

```
    const [ids, setIds] = useState(["ID#1", "ID#2"]).split("[\\s,]+")
    const [id, setId] = useState(addresses[0]);
```

Here is where I set the function for picking each individual ID and running the function

```
    const fetchNft = async (e) => {
        for(let i = 0; i< ids.length; i++){
        const _id = id[i]
        const idInfo = await find(_id);
        console.log(idInfo)
           }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't make any sense:

```
useState(["ID#1", "ID#2"]).split("[\\s,]+")
```

`useState` returns an array containing the state value and the setter function for the state value.  There's nothing to "split", and in this case neither of those values are strings.

You *probably* meant to put that `split` logic *here*:

```
setIds(event.target.value.split("[\\s,]+")
```

Since the input value is the string of comma-separated values that you want to split into an array.

Comment: Yes I did thank you very much for your answer and the education behind it.

Answer (score 0):

This can't possibly work

```
    const [ids, setIds] = useState(["ID#1", "ID#2"]).split("[\\s,]+")
```

You need to first call `useState` and then split on the first returned value. You can't split the return value of `useState` given that it is an array.